# How to handle nested loops with tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, nested-loops, loss-function

i am new to tensorflow. I am working with keras but for creating a customized loss function i am more or less forced to write a function in tensorflow. 
I get stuck at the point where i have to translate this following numpy for loop into tensorflow syntax.

```
for j in range(grid):
    for k in range(modes):
        for l in range(dim):
            for m in range(dim):
                lorentz[:,j,l,m] += 1J*osc_stre[:,l,m,k]/(energies[j]-e_j[:,k])
                if l == m == k:
                    lorentz[:,j,l,m] += 1
```

Here you can see the initial shapes of the arrays:

```
e_j = zeros([sample_nr,modes],dtype='complex')
osc_stre = zeros([sample_nr,dim,dim,modes],dtype='complex')
lorentz = zeros([sample_nr,grid,dim,dim],dtype='compex')
```

energies[j] has the shape (grid)

is it possible to handle this problem with tensorflow? Can anybody give me a hint how to translate this into tensorflow syntax? I have already tried a couple of things like the tensorflow while loop but one of the big problems is, that tensorflow objects do not support item assignment.

EDIT:

i think i've come up with a solution for this simplified verison of the problem:

```
for j in range(grid):
    for k in range(modes):
        lorentz[j] += 1J*osc_stre[k]/(energies[j]-e_j[k])
        if k == 0:
           lorentz[j] += 1
```

the solution:

```
lorentz_list = []
    tf_one = tf.ones([1], complex64)
    tf_i = tf.cast(tf.complex(0.,1.), complex64)
    energies_float = tf.cast(energies,float32)
    energies_complex = tf.complex(energies_float,tf.zeros([energy_grid],float32))
    for j in range(energy_grid):
        lorentz_list.append(tf.add(tf_one,tf.reduce_sum(tf.multiply(tf_i,tf.divide(osc_stre_tot,tf.subtract(energies_complex[j],e_j))),-1)))
    lorentz = tf.stack(lorentz_list)
```

Comment: Can you share the exact (and complete) shapes of "lorentz", "osc_stre", "energies" and "e_j"?

Comment: And in terms of "j,k,l,m".

Comment: @DanielMöller i added the shapes - hope this helps

Comment: Is "modes == dim == dim"?

Comment: you mean why i wrote  if l == m == k ? this is basically because i want to add a unitary matrix to the lorentzians. but modes and dim are different things in general

Comment: Yes, but are the dimensions the same? The numbers "dim" and "modes" are equal? (This may simplify the solution a little).

Comment: no, sadly they are not the same dimension in general. although they can be in some cases

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming these:

- `lorentz.shape == (batch, grid, dim, dim)` and was zero before the loop.
- `osc_stre.shape == (batch, dim, dim, modes)`
- `energies.shape == (grid,)`
- `e_j.shape == (batch, modes)`

Then:

```
osc_stre = K.reshape(osc_stre, (-1, 1, dim, dim, modes))
energies = K.reshape(energies, (1, grid, 1, 1, 1))   
e_j = K.reshape(e_j, (-1, 1, 1, 1, modes))

lorentz = 1J*osc_stre/(energies-e_j) 

identity = np.zeros((1, 1, dim, dim, modes))
for d in range(min(modes,dim)):
    identity[0,0,d,d,d] = 1
identity = K.variable(identity, dtype = tf.complex64)

lorentz += identity
lorentz = K.sum(lorentz, axis=-1)
```

Comment: i am trying this out but i'm getting an error message for the line "lorentz = ..." - Tensor conversion requested dtype float64 for Tensor with dtype complex128: 'Tensor("Reshape_58:0", shape=(1, 1, 1, 1, 2), dtype=complex128)'   -    i suppose i have to cast one of the tensors somehow, but i'm not familiar with the K. notation

Comment: Notice you don't need an instance of "lorentz" before the line in my code (if it was made of zeros)

Comment: The problem is very probably with `osc_stre`, `energies` or `e_j`, they need to be all of the same type, `tf.complex64`. Or maybe `tf.complex128` (but I'm not sure this exists).

Comment: energies = K.cast(energies,complex128)  - this does the trick. but i'm still getting some errors that i'm trying to work out

Comment: thank you - this is really an elegant way to do this, i wouldn't have thought of it. it seems to work. i've only tried it with dim=1 and modes=2 because there i have data to compare it with but i will try with different values in the future.